# Apache POI converter, docx to pdf exception

Tags: java, apache, pdf, apache-poi, docx

I need to add table to existing docx document and then convert it to Pdf file, so Im using Apache POI and Apache POI converter libs.
There is my code:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTJc;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblGrid;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STJc;
....
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("e:\\projects\\1.docx");
   XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
   fis.close();
   XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();

//added to satisfy poi docx->pdf converter and avoid future npe on getCTTbl().getTblGrid()...
   CTTblGrid ctg = table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid();
   table.getCTTbl().setTblGrid(ctg);

   fillTable(table);

   OutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("e:\\projects\\1.pdf"));
   PdfOptions options= PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding("UTF-8");
   PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(doc, pdfFile, options);
}

private static XWPFTable fillTable(XWPFTable table) {
        //create first row
        XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
        tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
        tableRowOne.getCell(1).setText("col two, row one");
        tableRowOne.getCell(2).setText("col three, row one");
        //create second row
        XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.getRow(1);
        tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
        tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
        tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");
        //create third row
        XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.getRow(2);
        tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
        tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
        tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

        //align center
        CTTblPr tblPr = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr();
        CTJc jc = (tblPr.isSetJc() ? tblPr.getJc() : tblPr.addNewJc());
        jc.setVal(STJc.CENTER);

        //added to satisfy poi docx->pdf converter and avoid npe on getTcPr().getWidth()
        for(int i = 0; i < table.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
            XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(i);
            int numCells = row.getTableCells().size();
            for(int j = 0; j < numCells; j++){
                XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(j);

                CTTcPr ct = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
                cell.getCTTc().setTcPr(ct);

            }
        }

        return table;
    }
```

But I receive a such exception:

> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of columns in PdfPTable
>   constructor must be greater than zero.    at
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45)

But if just write my edited docx document (w/o conversion) to the file using:

```
doc.write(new File("e:\\projects\\1.docx"));
```

it shows me the well-formed table inside:
[image]

So I cant figure out why I receive "*The number of columns in PdfPTable constructor must be greater than zero.*" exception, when my created table has 3 rows and 3 columns.
Looks like some issue with pdf converter or I create table in the wrong way.
Maybe someone could suggest something to me?

Comment: There is no class `PdfConverter` in Apache POI - where is that class coming from?

Comment: I use this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf/1.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Change packages "*org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf*" to packages "*fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf*".

In this part.:

```
 PdfOptions options= PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding("UTF-8");
 PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(doc, pdfFile, options);
```

To.:

```
  fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions options = fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding("windows-1250");
  fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, pdfFile, options);
```